# How to setup Listview when receiving data from database

Tags: vb.net, listview

I can print my data to listview, but the result is totally messed up. how do i setup my listview properly?

```
Do While Not rs.EOF

   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("BetID").Value)
   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("FightNumber").Value)
   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("BetOption").Value)
   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("Amount").Value)
   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("TransactionDate").Value)
   listRecentTransactions.Items.Add(rs.Fields("Barcode").Value)
   i = i + 1
rs.MoveNext()
Loop
```

heres the result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set up your colums in design view.

[image]

In the code call `.BeginUpdate`. This prevents the ListView from redrawing until the `.EndUpdate` is called. This speeds things up because redrawing your screen is a slow process.

Next, create a new `List(Of T)` to hold the list items.

On each iteration of the loop we create a new list item and set its properties from the recordset data. After the properties are set the list item is added to the `List(Of ListViewItem)` (not the `ListView`) and we move to the next record.

After the loop the entire list is added to the `Items` collection of the `ListView` with `.AddRange`. Since `.AddRange` is expecting an array call `.ToArray` on the list.

Finally, call `.EndUpdate` on the `ListView`. This is where the data actually appears in the `ListView` all at once so the screen only has to redraw once.

I really wish you would stop using ADODB and move into this century with ADO.net.

```
Private Sub LoadListView()
    listRecentTransactions.BeginUpdate()
    Dim lst As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Dim li As New ListViewItem
        li.Text = rs.Fields("BetID").Value)
        li.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("FightNumber").Value)
        li.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("BetOption").Value)
        li.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("Amount").Value)
        li.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("TransactionDate").Value)
        li.SubItems.Add(rs.Fields("Barcode").Value)
        lst.Add(li)
        rs.MoveNext()
    Loop
    listRecentTransactions.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
    listRecentTransactions.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```